# How to update a field in Model B using onchange in the field of model A ? Odoo 12

Tags: odoo

What i'm trying to achieve is ,When updating a field in model A ,i needs to update a field in model B using onchange method

```
_name = 'Model_A' 

health_profile = fields.Many2one('health.profile', domain="[('partner_id', '=', partner_id)]", string="Health Profile")

@api.onchange('health_profile')
    def get_health_profile_specialist(self):

        ctx = self.health_profile.id
        res = self.env['model_B'].browse(ctx)
        return res.update({'specialist_name': self.specialist_name})
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand there is no need to modify the field with an onchange. You can directly check the value in the model A field, you could directly use a related field

```
health_profile = fields.Many2one('health.profile', domain="[('partner_id', '=', partner_id)]", string="Health Profile")
specialist_id = fields.Many2one('<yourmodel>', related='health_profile.specialist_id')
```

Maybe you should explain yourself better.

Comment: thankyou for the response,Ive worked on it,retrurn statement was throwing error,its running fine now.

Comment: why write() method not update() ?
what is the difference between them ?